# Converting an array of floating point pixels in [0,1] to grayscale image in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a 400x1 numpy array of floating point numbers in the interval [0,1] representing the pixels of an image, i.e., if resized to 20x20 it would be the desired picture. I want to convert this to a grayscaled image in Python. To completely reproduce my error, I have put my array in [this pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/xwXRJAH6). My code is

```
pixels = np.array(pixels)
img = Image.fromarray(pixels.reshape((20,20)), mode='LA')
img = img.resize((140, 140), Image.LANCZOS)
img.show()
```

which results in

[image]

The image is supposed to be a 7.

Comment: "not doing the trick" - explain (include the complete error message in your question).

Comment: I added my error.

Comment: Assuming `Image` is coming from module `PIL`, I cannot reproduce your error (Python 3.4.5 , PIL 4.0.0)

Comment: I copy pasted the wrong code (sorry!). I completely reproduceable example is given in the question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming 'pixels' is a python list of floats between 0 and 1,

```
pixels = 255 * (1.0 - pixels)
pixels.resize((20,20))
im = Image.fromarray(pixels.astype(np.uint8), mode='L')
im = im.resize((140, 140))
im.show()
```